# Ruby - IPSocket.getaddress returning ipv6 address

Tags: ruby

I'm running the following command expecting to get an ipv4 address, but getting an ipv6 instead:

```
[dummyhost]# ruby -rsocket -e 'p IPSocket.getaddress("google.com")'
"2404:6800:4006:811::200e"
```

`nslookup` is returning both ipv4 and ipv6:

```
[dummyhost]# nslookup google.com
Server:     232.159.207.1
Address:    232.159.207.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.250.67.14
Name:   google.com
Address: 2404:6800:4006:811::200e
```

Any idea why ipv6 is returned? and how can I get it to return ipv4 instead? Ruby  version below :

```
[dummyhost]#  ruby -v
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux]
```

Thanks
J